# Find an element in protractor -dropdown list

Tags: angular, protractor

I have to track an element from the following element sets which is designed in a dropdown and it should be selected for protractor e2e  , appreciate your comments on this,

`<option value="5250539" ng-repeat="option in cell.field.selectOptions track by $index" id="5250539" ng-selected="option.id == cell.data.data" class="ng-binding ng-scope">010:sometext
</option>`

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show bigger picture of HTML? It's important to see HTML with dropdown also

Comment: These questions are almost the same and should provide you a solution:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599450/how-to-select-option-in-drop-down-protractorjs-e2e-tests

And

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266723/dropdown-in-protractor-with-typescript/50910643#50910643

Comment: @Oleksii Thanks for replying , it's okey for now I tried the answer bellow and it, worked,@ Silvan thanks for posting the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protractor's API Docs give a good example of how you can filter a result set to click a specific result. This is how you'll want to click the single option in the dropdown list.

```
element.all(by.css('.items li')).filter(function(elem, index) {
  return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
    return text === 'Third';
  });
}).first().click();
```

Docs available here:
https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter

Comment: Thanks for help @  Vegthetics

Comment: @LakmalRajith anytime :) don't forget to choose it as the accepted answer if its resolved your issue (tick underneath)